# How do I dispose inner observable while using Switch statement

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a nested IObservable and I am using switch statement from Rx which helps me to dispose previous sequences. But what if I want to dispose manually? Disposing outer sequence is not an option.

```
_performSearchSubject
.Select(_ => return PerformQuery())
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(HandleResponseStream, HandleError);
```

PerformQuery returns `IObservable<Result>`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some time I found it myself... So the answer is:

You can use `TakeUntil(IObservable<TOther>)`, and then just pass in a new subject which can be called whenever you want to cancel previous stream. I think it is similar to what Switch() statement does in the underlying streams.

Final code looks liek this:

```
Subject<Unit> _cancellationObservable = new Subject<Unit>();

_performSearchSubject
.Select(_ => {
                return PerformQuery().TakeUntil(_cancellationObservable);
              })
            .Switch()
            .Subscribe(HandleResponseStream, HandleError);
```

And whenever I want to cancel it, I just call this guy:

```
_cancellationObservable.OnNext(Unit.Default);
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. Your 'PerformQuery' stream will already get disposed of when your _performSearchSubject subscription is disposed of.

Comment: @H_Andr I think the point is that Vidas does not want to dispose the outer observable. He wants to cancel the current inner observable and simply continue with the next inner observable when it arrives.

Comment: @TimothyShields - spot on. That is what I exactly want, disposing outer stream is not intended.

Comment: OK, fair enough - yes, in that case, TakeUntil seems suitable. You could still probably write it without newing up a subject each time. Why not reuse the same subject instance? Do you even need to use subjects at all? Your comment mentioned "click stop in UI". Why not make it an observable stream, from your click event? e.g. Observable.FromEvent. If it is a VM command, then you can still turn this into an Observable.

Comment: Absolutely right with reusing the same subject. I actually did that originally in my code, just not renewed the answer, but will do as follows. What is related to clickevent, as it is actually an ICommand, I would then be in a need of an event for it.

Answer (score 0):

The Observable stream returned by 'PerformQuery' will automatically be disposed of when either:

- Your 'Switch' statement executes due to a new '_performSearchSubject'. i.e. the previous stream will be cleaned up by the 'Switch' operator.
  OR
- Your overall query is disposed of.

You should store the disposable returned by your .Subscribe and use this to clean up your subscription. Your use of an internal subject is unnecessary.

Have you actually tried your original solution?
Here is some Linqpad code to prove the point:

```
var inner = Observable.Create<string>((o) =>
{
    o.OnNext("First item of new inner");
    return Disposable.Create(() => "Inner Disposed".Dump());
});

var outer = Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.MinValue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
        .Select(_ => inner)
        .Switch()
        .Subscribe(output => output.Dump());


Console.ReadLine();

outer.Dispose();
```

You will notice that no matter when you hit a key and enter (to move past the Console.ReadLine), your inner observable stream will be disposed of. Similarly, your Switch statement will clean up any previous streams each time the Timer fires.

You can still use a 'TakeUntil' if you want this to be controlled based on an unrelated stream, but, it is better to just use the disposable rerturned if you can.

Comment: Well I cannot call outer dispose because it needs to be alive, I care about disposing current active inner IObservable. I do not need it to finish, I need it to be stopped the same second I click stop in my UI.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I misunderstood the question. You should avoid using a subject though if you don't need to (and it sounds like you don't, based on the fact your trigger is a UI event).